# Update separate thread CWinThread form with text information

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have program that has status window on separate thread. I need to make status thread form update with new text information information. What is the best way of doing that?

Main thread creates status window:

```
void CMainWindow::OnPushButtonClicked ()   
{   
    CWinThread* pThread= AfxBeginThread(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMySecondUIThreadClass) );
}
```

UI thread:

```
class CMySecondUIThreadClass : public CWinThread
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CMySecondUIThreadClass)

protected:
    CMySecondUIThreadClass();
    virtual ~CMySecondUIThreadClass();

public:
    CMainWindow * v1;
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();
    virtual int ExitInstance();

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

InitInstance of UI:

```
BOOL CMySecondUIThreadClass::InitInstance()
{
    v1 = new CMainWindow;
    v1->Inform("Thread");  //Procedure that updates vi dialog form controls with text information
    m_pMainWnd=v1;
    ShowWindow (m_pMainWnd->m_hWnd,SW_SHOW);
    m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow ();
    return TRUE;

}
```

Comment: Typical approach is to have all UI on one thread (main thread), and perform long-running tasks on background threads. Then you have only 2 points of cross-thread access: when starting the job (from UI to woker) and when finishing it/reporting progress (from worker to UI)

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to match your code. You have CMainWindow creating a thread which creates a CMainWindow?  What is the "status thread form?"

Comment: On prototyping stage I'm planing to have two same looking forms, just first one will be responsible on doing job and second one will show status information